# Mysql if duplicate UNIQUE KEY update Hits

Tags: php, mysql, insert, duplicates

My simple php script for inset keyword. If keyword is already exit i need update hits counter.. How can i do it? if keyword is "sample" if already is there in db i need update "hits" = 2 , if again same keyword "hits" =3

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `search` (
      `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `hits` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
      UNIQUE KEY `keyword` (`keyword`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=22 ;
```

my php:

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("INSERT INTO search (keyword, date) VALUES    ('$keyword', '$date' )");
```

Comment: @Darren the op is doing an insert query, not an update and wants to know how to not insert an additional row with a keyword instead of just incrementing the hits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `ON DUPLICATE KEY`?

```
INSERT INTO table (columns) 
    VALUES (values)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits = hits + 1
```

because you have a unique key on keyword it will increment the hits by 1

SIDE NOTE:

dont use PHP's mysql_* **[deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php)** API it has a lot of security issues. You should instead use parameterized queries with **[mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** or **[PDO](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)**

Comment: @Higginslpert glad I could help :) ON DUPLICATE KEY is a very useful tool, just make sure if you use it for something else that you know how it works :) +1 for the question